# Outlook 2003 SBE randomly restarts opening some Asian Email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

We have a user with Outlook 2003 SBE. When an email is opened from certain Asian companies Outlook will randomly throw up an Outlook has crashed message send a report to Microsoft and restarts.

I have tried setting up Outlook for the user on another PC but this still happens, I have tried another user with SBE this still happens.

Changing it to Rich text crashed it also, and done the usual repair but to no avail. Setting up the User on an Outlook 2010 profile seems to fix the problem - but they have 2003 SBE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We bought and installed Office 2010 in the end. Although not a real solution this has gotten rid of the issue.